# Spectral Radius of Perturbed Matrix

Tags: spectral-radius, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A$ be an n-dimensional square matrix such that each entry of $A$ lies in $[0,1]$, i.e., $a_{ij} \in [0,1]$ for all $1\le i,j\le n$. Let $\widetilde{A}$ be a perturbed version of $A$ where some entries of $\widetilde{A}$ might be larger than those in $A$ and the rest equal, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
1 \ge \widetilde{a}_{ij} \ge a_{ij} \text{ for all } i,j \\
\widetilde{a}_{ij} > a_{ij} \text{ for some } i,j.
\end{align*}
I am working on a problem where it would help me to have the spectral radius $\widetilde{\rho}$ of $\widetilde{A}$ to be at least the spectral radius $\rho$ of $A$ and wondering if this would be true?

Any help would be appreciated on the intuition of why or why not it may hold. With thanks.

Comment: The question does not meet the MSE guidelines (too short, missing elements). Have a look at this post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/1107523

Comment: Depends on what "increase" means to you: "Strictly increase" no, "weakly increase" yes.

Comment: One more question where the immediate comment is "Begin by  making $10^6$ numerical attempts by simulation" for $2 \times 2$ matrices for example. This is a max. 10 lines program in Matlab, Python, etc...  It will help you to build a more precise conjecture.

Comment: Do you know Gelfand's formula for the spectral radius?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and suggestions. Looking at Gelfand's formula now, it followed easily. Thank you again!

Comment: For the specific case of nonnegative matrices, you can also approach this with Frobenius-Perron theory. In particular, this is one part of Wielandt’s theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and any matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ it is known that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|A^n\|^{1/n} = \rho(A)$. Now let $A=(a_{ij}),B=(b_{ij})$ be nonnegative matrices. If $A \le B$, that is $a_{ij} \le b_{ij}$ $(i,j=1,\dots,n)$, check that then $A^n \le B^n$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$. Next, consider the row sum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (or any other matrix norm which is nondecreasing on the set of nonnegative matrices). Now $\|A^n\|_\infty \le \|B^n\|_\infty$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$, hence $\|A^n\|_\infty^{1/n} \le \|B^n\|_\infty^{1/n}$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$. As $n \to \infty$ this yields $\rho(A) \le \rho(B)$. Summing up, if $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is ordered by the coordinatewise ordering then the spectral radius is nondecreasing on the set of nonnegative matrices.

Finally, a strict inequality in one entry in general does not imply a strict inequality for the spectral radius: For
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right), \quad
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right)
$$
we have $\rho(A)=\rho(B)=1$.